# spark withcolumn create a column duplicating values from existining column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am having problem figuring this.  Here is the problem statement 
 lets say  I have a dataframe, I want to select value for column c where  column b value is foo and create a new column D  and repeat the vale "3" for all rows

```
+---+----+---+
|  A|   B|  C|
+---+----+---+
|  4|blah|  2|
|  2|    |  3|
| 56| foo|  3|
|100|null|  5|
+---+----+---+

want it to become:
+---+----+---+-----+
|  A|   B|  C|  D  |
+---+----+---+-----+
|  4|blah|  2|  3  |
|  2|    |  3|  3  |
| 56| foo|  3|  3  |
|100|null|  5|  3  |
+---+----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to extract the column `C` value  i.e. `3` with `foo` in column `B`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val value = df.filter(col("B") === "foo").select("C").first()(0)
```

Then use that value using `withColumn` to create a new column `D` using `lit` function

```
df.withColumn("D", lit(value)).show(false)
```

You should get your desired output.